# How do I make a histogram from my python data for four keys?

Tags: python, excel, histogram

I am trying to make histograms for my data samples, which gives me results for four keys. I am making one histogram for each key. However, I do not know how to extract the data in Excel, or whether there is a better way to plot from python?

My data comes out like this:

```
{'EX_D': 8, 'P_H_U': 2, 'HY_D': 5, 'HYDROPH_U': 0}
{'EX_D': 2, 'P_H_U': 7, 'HY_D': 1, 'HYDROPH_U': 4}
```

How do I export the data and separate the results for each key?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you might wish to learn [`pyplot`](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) - see e.g. http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html

Answer (score 0):

For a quick'n'dirty export of your data, you can print out tab- or comma-separated values:

```
data = [{'EX_D': 8, 'P_H_U': 2, 'HY_D': 5, 'HYDROPH_U': 0},
        {'EX_D': 2, 'P_H_U': 7, 'HY_D': 1, 'HYDROPH_U': 4}]
keys = ['EX_D', 'P_H_U', 'HY_D', 'HYDROPH_U']
print("\t".join(keys))
for d in data:
    print("\t".join(str(d[k]) for k in keys))
```

And copy&paste to Excel to do a [histogram analysis](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Present-your-data-in-a-histogram-ccc0fc1a-2ccd-490f-a346-87f3084cc26e):

```
EX_D   P_H_U  HY_D   HYDROPH_U
8      2      5      0
2      7      1      4
```

Comment: @user1903 If that's useful and solved your problem, please accept this answer.